# Something wrong with knockout-kendo pager of gird

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I'm working with grid, everything is perfect: i can update delete and add rows, and changes are being updated immediatly
but i have a problem with the pager:
even in example page 
http://rniemeyer.github.com/knockout-kendo/web/Grid.html

,when records in grid are fewer than   one pageSize :
the message is on pager is:"NaN - NaN of 3 items"  (which is wrong, it must be like "1 - 1 of 3 items")
Is where any workaround to solve this little problem?

Thanks Forward

Comment: Interesting, did you try with the latest version? It sounds like it should be covered.

Comment: As i wrote - the problem is even in the "example" of the site (so ithink it is latest)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is because `pageSize` is not defined. For demonstrating it, define a grid with `id` set to grid. Then add the following HTML tag:

```
<a id="fix" href="#" class="k-button">Fix</a>
```

and the following JavaScript code:

```
$("#fix").on("click", function () {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.pageSize(2);
});
```

You will see that initially it shows the `NaN - NaN of 3 items` but as soon as you `click` on *Fix* `button` it will show `1 - 2 of 3 items`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, thank you very much OnaBai, you helped me very much.
Meanwhile i found another trick, for writing the same thing in knockoutjs customHandler way :

```
 <div id="parcels_Grid" data-bind="kendoGrid:{ dataSource:
 {data:someData
 ,pageSize:3} 
 ,data:someData, rowTemplate: 'rowParcelTmpl', altRowTemplate:   
 'altParcelTmpl',   useKOTemplates: true }"> </div>
```

Notice, that you must specify either the "dataSource" and "data" attributes (otherwise it should not work)

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually removed the data: someData declaration inside of dataSource and it worked fine for me as well. I like this better because it keeps everything declarative.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="grid" class="grid" data-bind="kendoGrid: {
data: Reminderlist, scrollable: false, resizable: true, selectable: false, scrollable: false, sortable: true, selectable: 'multiple cell', pageable: true, groupable: true, dataSource: { pageSize: 20 },
                           columns: [{ field: 'Duration', title: 'Duration' },
                                     { field: 'Subject', title: 'Subject' },
                                     { field: 'EmailMessage', title: 'Email Message' },
                                     { field: 'SMSText', title: 'Message Text' }
                                    ], change: GridChange
}">
</div>
```

`dataSource: { pageSize: 20 }` specify like this....

if u mention only `pageSize: 20` like this ,it doesn't works in sometiomes